# NSString loses its value inside a view controller

Tags: ios

In my app I am passing some strings from a view controller to another view controller.

- View Controller A = MainViewController
- View Controller B = NuevoServicioViewController

**Passing NString from A to B**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nuevo_servicio_segue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"estoy en segue pasando a nuevo servicio");
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        NuevoServicioViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        //pasamos la latitud del PO
        //la convertimos a String
        NSString *latitud  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20f", self.puntoOrigen.latitude];
        vc.parametro_origin_latitude = latitud;
        //lo comprobamos
        NSLog(@"LATITUD DEL PO PASADA=%@",latitud);
        //pasamos la lONGITUD del PO
        //la convertimos a String
        NSString *longitud  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20f", self.puntoOrigen.longitude];
        vc.parametro_origin_longitude = longitud;
        //lo comprobamos
        NSLog(@"LONGITUD DEL PO PASADA=%@",longitud);

    }
}
```

**Log view to verify that the string is correct:**

```
2015-03-12 22:37:31.966 ABCTaxi[811:60b] LATITUD DEL PO PASADA=31.71179790294406686257
```

**Now in B, log to check that the string is received:**

```
 //3. origin_latitude, la recibimos de mainview

    NSLog(@"LATITUD RECIBIDA DE MAINVIEW=%@",self.parametro_origin_latitude);
```

**Log view to verify that the received string is the same:**

```
[811:60b] LATITUD RECIBIDA DE MAINVIEW=31.71179790294406686257
```

**And at the end of B, button action method prior to further process, another log to verify that the string is correct:**

```
- (IBAction)boton_tomar_taxi_action:(id)sender {
    //COMPROBAMOS QUE ESTAN TODOS LOS PARAMETROS
    //PARAMETRO 1 CLIENT
    NSLog(@"client = %@", self.parametro_client);
    //PARAMETRO 2 ORIGIN
      NSLog(@"origin = %@", self.parametro_origin);
    //PARAMETRO 3 ORIGIN_LATITUDE
    NSLog(@"origin_latitude = %@", self.parametro_origin_latitude);
    //PARAMETRO 4 ORIGIN_LATITUDE
    NSLog(@"origin_longitude = %@", self.parametro_origin_longitude);
    //PARAMETRO 5. DATE
    NSLog(@"date = %@", self.parametro_date);

}
```

And finally the string is **null**.

```
[811:60b] origin_latitude = (null)
```

I can't find the reason why the string is not the same at the end.
Please, help me to identify the reason.
Thank you

Comment: How did you declare the parametro_origin_longitude property?

Comment: @bensarz:, I am following the string parameter_origin_latitude, declared in the h file as    property (weak, nonatomic)NSString *parametro_origin_latitude;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your property to strong, this should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change this `@property (weak, nonatomic)NSString *parametro_origin_latitude;` to this `@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *parametro_origin_latitude;`